# Table for variable exclusions in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, lookup

Sorry if this explanation is unclear in any points.  I'm working in Oracle.

I have a large table which is structured with columns for Country, Division, SubDivision, SpendCategory, etc.  I need to create potentially flexible exclusion criteria for each country for this large table, and was thinking about creating a second 'exclusions table' like so.

```
 CREATE TABLE EXCLUSIONS

 (COUNTRY VARCHAR(50), EXCLUSIONFIELD VARCHAR(50), FIELDVALUE VARCHAR(50));
```

My idea was that I could populate this table with rows like

```
 Mexico - Division - "Central Division"

 Mexico - SubDivision - "Mexico City"

 France - Division - "Paris Division"
```

> ...
>
> And with this table, automatically filter my table to exclude data
>   where (country=Mexico AND division="central division"),
>   (country=Mexico AND subdivision="Mexico City"), (country=France AND
>   division="paris division"),

...

So I guess I have two questions.  First, is this the best way to do this?  I like this idea because the exclusion list is potentially long and having a third party maintain a table seems more feasible than manually updating large numbers of where conditions.  Second, how would I write the query to exclude all conditions from the Exclusions table from my main table?

Comment: How about keeping the same structure for the exclusions table and the select * from table where (country, division, subdivision, spendcategory) not in (select country, division, subdivision, spendcategory from exclusions)?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing can work, but the query will look something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from exclusions e
                  where e.exclusionfield = 'country' and e.value = t.country or
                        e.exclusionfield = 'district' and e.value = t.district or
                        . . .
                  );
```

This can be a very hard query to optimize.  You might want to express this using separate subqueries:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from exclusions e
                  where e.exclusionfield = 'country' and e.value = t.country 
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1
```

from exclusions e
                      where e.exclusionfield = 'district' and e.value = t.district
                     );

You should be able to get reasonable performance with an index on `exclusions(value, exclusionfield)`.

An alternative would be to replicate the columns . . . `country`, `district` and so on, removing the `exclusionfield` column:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from exclusions e
              from e.country = t.country or
                   e.district = t.district or
                   . . .
             );
```

This might also optimize better with separate `exists` subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude data you can use not exist(select 1 from condition_table where ....)
You can also use condition with (country, subdivision) not in(....)
To filter select with some data, you can define table dynamically using 'with' clause before select...